# Issue with Scale widget using tickinterval

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

The widget shows tick using tickinterval when following code shown below,

```
from Tkinter import *
slider_1 = Scale(mGui,orient=HORIZONTAL,length = 100,from_=0,to=9, tickinterval =1).pack()
```

However it throws error with the following code

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
slider_1 = Scale(mGui,orient=HORIZONTAL,length = 100,from_=0,to=9, tickinterval =1).pack()
```

Error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-tickinterval"
```

Why is it so? Is it a bug or problem with the installation. For information i am using Python 2.7.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `ttk` module contains also a `Scale` widget, and you are actually using the `Scale` widget from `ttk` and not from `Tkinter`. Widgets in the `ttk` module are customised and styled differently from Tkinter widgets.

Check the following documentation on `ttk` for more information regarding its widgets:

> [ttk — Tk themed widgets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ttk.html)

To solve your problem, you could remove your second global import and simply do:

```
import ttk
```

Then, every time you want to use a widget from `ttk`, you can simply prefix it with `ttk.`.